# Spring Integration 4 asynchronous request/response

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-dsl

I am trying to write a simple message flow using Spring Integration v4's DSL APIs which would look like this:

```
       -> in.ch -> Processing -> JmsGatewayOut -> JMS_OUT_QUEUE
Gateway
       <- out.ch <- Processing <- JmsGatewayIn <- JMS_IN_QUEUE
```

With the request/response being asynchronous, when I inject a message via the initial Gateway, the message goes all the way to JMS_OUT_QUEUE. Beyond this message flow, a reply message is put back into JMS_IN_QUEUE which it is then picked up by JmsGatewayIn. At this point, the message is Processed and placed into out.ch (I know the response gets to out.ch because I have a logger interceptor there which logs the message being placed there) but, the Gateway never receives the response.

Instead of a response, the system outside of this message flow which picked up the message from JMS_OUT_QUEUE and placed the response in JMS_IN_QUEUE, receives a `javax.jms.MessageFormatException: MQJMS1061: Unable to deserialize object` on its own JmsOutboundgateway (I think it is failing to deserialize a jms reply object from looking at the logs).

I have clearly not got something configured correctly but I don't know exactly what. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Working with spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE, spring-integration-jms-4.0.3.RELEASE, spring-integration-java-dsl-1.0.0.M2, spring-jms-4.0.6.RELEASE.

My Gateway is configured as follows:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface WsGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "in.ch", replyChannel = "out.ch", 
        replyTimeout = 45000)
    AResponse process(ARequest request);
}
```

My Integration flow is configured as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Bean(name = "in.ch")
    public DirectChannel inCh() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "out.ch")
    public DirectChannel outCh() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }   

    @Autowired
    private MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("in.ch")
                .handle("processor", "processARequest")
                .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(mqConnectionFactory)
                        .requestDestination("JMS_OUT_QUEUE")
                        .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow responseFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(mqConnectionFactory)
                .destination("JMS_IN_QUEUE"))
                .handle("processor", "processAResponse")
                .channel("out.ch")
                .get();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help on this,
PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your configuration is bad:

1. Since you start the flow from `WsGateway#process` you really should wait reply there.
   The gateway's request/reply capability is based on `TemporaryReplyChannel`, which is placed to the `headers` as non-serializable value.
2. As long as you wait rely on that gateway, actually there is no reason to provide the `replyChannel`, if you aren't going to do some publish-subscribe logic on the reply.
3. As you send message to the JMS queue, you should understand that consumer part might be a separete remote application. And the last one might know nothing about your `out.ch`.
4. The JMS request/reply capability is really based on `JMSCorrelationID`, but it isn't enough. The one more thing here is a `ReplyTo` JMS header. Hence, if you are going to send reply from the consumer you should really just rely on the `JmsGatewayIn` stuff.

So I'd change your code to this:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface WsGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "in.ch", replyTimeout = 45000)
    AResponse process(ARequest request);
}

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Bean(name = "in.ch")
    public DirectChannel inCh() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Autowired
    private MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("in.ch")
                .handle("processor", "processARequest")
                .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(mqConnectionFactory)
                        .requestDestination("JMS_OUT_QUEUE")
                        .replyDestination("JMS_IN_QUEUE"))
                .handle("processor", "processAResponse")
                .get();
    }

}
```

Let me know, if it is appropriate for you or try to explian why you use `two-way` gateways for one `one-way` cases. Maybe `Jms.outboundAdapter()` and `Jms.inboundAdapter()` are more good for you?

**UPDATE**

How to use `<header-channels-to-string>` from Java DSL:

```
.enrichHeaders(e -> e.headerChannelsToString())
```

Comment: Hi, your solution is correct, thanks. I had first tried replacing the Jms In/Out Gateways with Jms In/Out Adapters but had trouble configuring those too. Then I tried only Jms Out Gateway with replyDestination as in your solution and that worked okay. I hadn't removed the initial @Gateway's replyChannel which, as you mentioned, is not needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hello again, I find myself needing to come back to this post... I have a requirement where I believe I do need to use separate JMS Inbound/Outbound adapters to allow for asynchronous responses. In order to do this, I have again set a replyChannel="out.ch" on WsGateway, switched the Jms.outboundGateway to both a Jms.outboundAdapter and Jms.inboundAdapter and, have set JMSCorrelationID header on the message before sending out but, when response comes back and placed into out.ch, the WsGateway does not pick up the response message? My SI flow is actually a bit more complicated than shown here...

Comment: Try to use `<header-enricher>` with `<header-channels-to-string>` before sending request

Comment: How would I use `header-channels-to-string` in the new DSL form? Is it simply a case of setting it as a header name with null value?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I forget that you use DSL already. I am adding a sample to my answer

Comment: I am using spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.0.M2 which doesn't seem to have `e.headerChannelsToString()` available to it. Is that included in a newer version of the package? M2 is the latest I can see in http://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-java-dsl.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, you have to do this workaround: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/blob/master/spring-integration-java-dsl/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/HeaderEnricherSpec.java#L145

Comment: Excellent. With the workaround the response is received by the initial WsGateway okay. I can also see the response contains the necessary header replyChannel in the following form: `replyChannel=fd972c0f-ec93-4dad-b6f5-ea7ede3b98ed:1`. Thanks again Artem, and I'll keep an eye out for `e.headerChannelsToString()` appearing in the next DSL milestone jar hopefully!

Comment: Great! It will be released on the next week, just before SpringOne. Follow, please, with Spring IO News and Feeds